# Combining two dataset in R with conditional overwriting & coding momentum trading

Tags: r, merge

I have looked around the website but could not find any post that answers my question.

```
q<-ifelse(c$Action_PX != z & c$Above == 1,log(z/c$Action_PX, base = exp(1)),NA)
w<-ifelse(c$Action_PX != z & c$Below == 1,log(c$Action_PX/z, base = exp(1)),NA)
```

I am building a momentum trading model, and these functions calculate my return when I decide to make a trade (when momentum changes). As of now, I am getting something like this when I run this model:

```
q       w          -> (I want)  z
NA      NA                      NA
NA      NA                      NA
NA      NA                      NA
0.012   NA                      0.012                      
NA      NA                      NA
NA      0.005                   0.005
```

Is there any way I can combine these two(q and w), overwrite only numbers, so that it looks like z? Any help is much appreciated!

For your reference, Above is a binary variable that becomes 1 when spot price is more than the moving average, and the opposite goes for Below. I go long when momentum changes from below to above, I go short when it changes from above to below. z is just another set of data created by adding 0 at the beginning of Action_PX series to get the momentum. I tried using for loop but I could not get it to work, so I decided to stick with more manual way. Any suggestion to improve my model is also very much appreciated.

Comment: How about `pmin(q, w, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: It works!!! This is such a brilliant way. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `apply` and `min`

```
 apply(df1, 1, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else min(x, na.rm=TRUE))
 #[1]    NA    NA    NA 0.012    NA 0.005
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! have a great day